# How do i access a specific text from text childNode of some <div> using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="mtb-desc">
    some contentsome contentsome contentsome  contentsome contentsome contentsome contentsome content.

    some contentsome contentsome contentsome entsome contentsome contentsome contentsome contentsome.

    NO : 212122Name is Jone</div>
<span class="mtb-price">
<label Class="mtb-ofr"><b class="lb1"></b>WWWW</label></span>
<script>
var eg1 = document.querySelectorAll('.mtb-desc')[0].childNodes[0].split(null)[1].nodeValue;
var eg2 = document.querySelectorAll('.mtb-ofr')[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue = eg1;
alert(eg2);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In above code i want to replace WWWW with text Name is Jone. so how do i access 'Name is Jone' text from that text node ?

Comment: You do not have 'wwww' in your markup, only 'WWWW'. Please edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the ending non-numeric text and insert it where WWWW is, do this:

```
var content = document.querySelectorAll('.mtb-desc')[0].innerText;
var insertion = content.match(/[^0-9]+$/)[0];
document.querySelectorAll('.mtb-ofr')[0].innerText = insertion;
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for Answer but i have another question and that is what if i want to replace WWWW with 'Starts from Rs. 1000' instead of 'Name is Jone'

Comment: Is that just an arbitrary string or is that somewhere in the markup?